# Could not use HDMI with only single VGA controller connected with iGPU

Tags: linux, nvidia, intel-graphics, optimus

I have a laptop with i7-12700H and RTX 2050, with only a single VGA controller connected with iGPU. `lspci | grep -iE "vga|3d"` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 2050] (rev a1)
```

I have an HDMI port on the side of my laptop, which works well while using windows and booting Linux (for example, under grub). However, once `i915` driver is loaded, the external screen become black and complains "no signal".

This is my kernel log: https://fars.ee/gQTL

Could anyone figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Please ask this question here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov But my VGA controller is connected to Intel iGPU instead of NVIDIA ones. Is it really related to nvida？